# Problem collecting data from ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to collect data using ReactiveForms. The scheme of my modules are the following:
Firstly I'm creating a [modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal) which will collect the data:

```
async present(){
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: dataComponent,
  cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
  swipeToClose: true,
  presentingElement: this.routerOutlet.nativeEl
});

modal.onDidDismiss().then((returned)=>{
  if (returned !== null) {
    this.returned = returned.data;
    alert('Modal Sent Data :'+ JSON.stringify(returned));
  }
});

return await modal.present(); 
}
```

Then in the dataComponent (the modal) I have a simple form

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="slideOneForm" >
  <ion-list lines="none" class="form-list">
      <ion-item class="rellenable" color="light">
          <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="name" type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
  
      <ion-item class="rellenable" color="light">
        <ion-label position="floating">Description</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="description" type="text" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar button tappable (click)="submit()">
    <ion-title >Create</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I added ngModel, on the inputs even though the use of the ngModel in reactive forms is deprecated. I also tried, removing the ngModels:

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="slideOneForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <ion-list lines="none" class="form-list">
      <ion-item class="rellenable" color="light">
          <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="name" type="text"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
  
      <ion-item class="rellenable" color="light">
        <ion-label position="floating">Description</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="description" type="text" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="form-group">
        <ion-button type="submit" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
          Create
        </ion-button>
      </div>   
      </ion-list>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

But when I try calling the submit function

```
submit(){
    console.log(this.name)
}
```

Or in the second case

```
submit(){
    console.log(this.slideOneForm)
}
```

None of them will print correctly the name.In fact, when I use the ngSubmit, the modal closes without printing anything.

Comment: What do you get for `console.log(this.slideOneForm.value)`?

Comment: But as deprecation says, you should not use ngModel and formControlName. Keep only formControlName as the single source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

//You can try to Use in this way. and if you have ngModel Form you must use

[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </ion-input>
    <ion-button type="submit" expand="block" fill="clear" shape="round">
    Create
    </ion-button>
</form>
```

For printing

```
submit(){
    console.log(this.name)
}
```